# Traduce from node red mqtt node to python3 client

Tags: python-3.x, mqtt, node-red, paho

I am creating a web form for create mqtt clients. I am following the shape of mqtt nodes in node red, but, in my case, I will handle in the back_end using python3 paho-mqtt. The problem is I am not sure how match between all fields in the form with the back_end python3 client, mainlly in the tls configurations. Thank you in advance.
[image]

Comment: This question is far too vague.  You need show us what you've tried and what doesn't work.

Comment: "how match between all fields in the form " ?!?  match to what fields where?  Everything in your picture is an option on the connect() function call.

Comment: I am using the tls_set function to set the Certificate, Private Key and CA Certificate. But I don' know how to provide the Passphrase and the Verify server certificate option.